# Anyone used appcache and jquery mobile on a drupal site?

Tags: javascript, caching

Has anyone used the cache manifest to make a Drupal site work offline? Ive made a demo with static html files which seems to work fine, so im assuming it wouldn't be too hard to achieve the same thing with a Drupal site.

The way that you tell browsers that files have changed (and so need to be downloaded again) is by adding a comment to the cache manifest file so its byte size changes. Im not quite sure how to do this with Drupal but maybe some sort of server cron could run periodically? Personally im more interested in having a site that works offline rather than achieving ideal performance, so if the file was modified every hour rather than when content actually changed that would be fine for me.

If anyone has used appcache, has anyone done so with jquery mobile at the same time? What im after is a fully native feel to a site that's accessible offline. My static demo does this perfectly, so again I would have thought this would be achievable in Drupal.